# Spring MVC with spring boot data jpa on IntelliJ not recognized

Tags: spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to build a simple blog application but I am facing an issue with spring data jpa on IntelliJ. It must be some kind of IDE configuration I am missing as on another instance of IntelliJ on my other PC it is working fine...

Here is what I get

[image]

My pom.xml looks like this

```
`    <groupId>blog-dpalyov</groupId>
<artifactId>blog-project</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<packaging>pom</packaging>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>


<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

The classpath looks like this and I see the dependency added.

[image]

Already tried to add JPA as framework support (deleted the persistence.xml)

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: you could try "right click on project -> maven -> reimport"

Comment: Hi Alex. Already tried it but with no success.

Comment: Another combo to try File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart

Answer (score 0):

I had the error message

```
Kotlin: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved
```

Which I traced back to the fact that Intellij was missing the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency.

Invalidate Caches/Restart was not helping and neither was mvn clean and even deleting the maven repository. What helped in the end, was to `right click on project -> maven -> reimport`. Thank you alexbt in the comments for that tip and I leave it here for anyone stumbling over this error in the future.